# Rails 4.0.0 experiencing periodic RoutingError exception (404) for existing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma

The issue is that our site periodically renders 404 RoutingError exceptions for routes that exist; even the root route.

The issue seems to pop up during the busiest parts of the day. If you refresh the page, the page may render appropriately, or it may not.

If Puma is refreshed, the issue is temporarily relieved.

The puma logs for these 404 exceptions for routes that actually exist are the exact same for 404 exceptions that occur for routes that do not actually exist.  An example log is below:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] : "/app"
  actionpack (4.0.11.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.11.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.11.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
  request_store (1.1.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.11.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.11.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.11.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:79:in `call'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `call'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

This route does exist, but the server is still rendering a 404 to the request.

I'm at a loss for what is happening, so I've included the server's configuration below.

**General Server Information**

Ubuntu 14.04

Nginx 1.4.7

Puma 2.15.3

Ruby 2.2.0

Rails 4.0.11.1

**Nginx configuration**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**Nginx virtual host configuration**

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:/tmp/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred default_server;

  root /home/deployer/deploys/current/public;

  if ($http_host ~* domain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi|svg)$ {
    try_files $uri @puma;
  }

  location @puma {
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 51200;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 6400;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 250;  #4 minutes
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 60;
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name _;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_certificate      /home/deployer/ssl/tld/domain.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /home/deployer/ssl/tld/domain.key;

  root /home/deployer/deploys/current/public;

  if ($http_host !~* domain.com) {
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi|svg)$ {
    try_files $uri @puma;
  }

  location @puma {
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 51200;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 6400;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 250;  #4 minutes
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 60;
}
```

**Puma Configuration (config/puma.rb)**

```
workers Integer(4)
threads 12, 12

port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
```

**Puma Deployments via Capistrano**

```
exec su - deployer -c 'cd /home/deployer/deploys/releases/20160303234701; export PORT=5000; export RAILS_ENV=production;  export PUMA_WORKERS=4; bundle exec puma -e $RAILS_ENV --pidfile /tmp/puma.pid -C config/puma.rb -b unix:///tmp/puma.sock >> /var/log/domain-service/web-1.log 2>&1'
```

Comment: Lets see your routes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was traced to a `reload_routes!` call in a controller.